# Avoid collapsing Range Areas during Union

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating a display in vba for excel of a large and complex dataset. For this I would like to prepopulate an array with all the values/formulas as well as a set of range objects with format information, and then once all data has been generated I will apply all at once as it is significantly faster than updating each cell and format range individually.

For some formats like cell color, font and others - Union can be used to build the range which works excellently, however for things like surrounding borders I need to keep the range areas intact to avoid wrong formatting. I know I could use for instance a collection object storing each individual range and then cycle through them all, but I am surprised that I cannot find any way to create a range object with areas the way I want. Thus, this question is not especially around solving my problem, but more about if there are functions to control the range object than I yet haven't thought of. The problem is exemplified by the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Function MergeRanges_KeepingAreasIntact(rIn1 As Range, rIn2 As Range) As Range
    'Some error checking controlling if ranges are empty or on different worksheets left out for readability
    Set MergeRanges_KeepingAreasIntact = rIn1.Parent.Range(rIn1.Address(False, False) & "," & rIn2.Address(False, False))
End Function

Function MergeRanges_AreasNotIntact(rIn1 As Range, rIn2 As Range) As Range
    'Some error checking controlling if ranges are empty or on different worksheets left out for readability
    Set MergeRanges_AreasNotIntact = Union(rIn1, rIn2)
End Function

Sub Evaluate()
    Dim i As Long, rMerge As Range
    Debug.Print MergeRanges_KeepingAreasIntact(Sheet1.Range("A3:D7"), Sheet1.Range("A8:D12")).Address
    Debug.Print MergeRanges_AreasNotIntact(Sheet1.Range("A3:D7"), Sheet1.Range("A8:D12")).Address

'########################################################
' try to build a range object with the 100 first diagonal
' cells to demonstrate range function limitations
'########################################################
    On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To 100
            If i = 1 Then
                Set rMerge = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
            Else
                Set rMerge = MergeRanges_KeepingAreasIntact(rMerge, Sheet1.Cells(i, i))
            End If
            If i <> rMerge.Cells.Count Then
                Debug.Print "Areas count: ", i, "Address string length:", Len(rMerge.Address(False, False))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
'#############################################################
'The results from this sub will be:

'$A$3:$D$7,$A$8:$D$12
'$A$3:$D$12
'Areas count:   59           Address string length:       254
'#############################################################
End Sub
```

The function MergeRanges_AreasNotIntact is efficient but will fail when ranges are aligned side by side and share the same height, or aligned above-below and share the same width.

The other function "MergeRanges_KeepingAreasIntact" is both ugly, and most likely inefficient as it coverts ranges back and forth to address strings. Moreover it will fail when more than ~58 areas are needed as the string limit size for input to the range function is limited to 255 characters.

There is no Range.Areas.Add method, but is there any other way to build a range object with >58 areas, keeping aligned areas separate in the object?

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to be able to reference the entire range as one range? If not, you could just create a **collection** of cells and when using them, cycle through them one at a time:

```
Sub test()

    Dim RngColl As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    
    'add 100 cell references to the collection
    For i = 1 To 100
        RngColl.Add Cells(i, i)
    Next
    
    'cycle through each item (cell reference) and do something with it
    For Each c In RngColl
        c.Value = 1
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This works for 100 cells, or 10,000.

Comment: The would be the " I know I could use for instance a collection object storing each individual range and then cycle through them all" in my original post, but thanks anyway. This is how I work now, but due to optimizations I would like to explore using pure "Ranges".

Comment: Apologies, I don't know how but I missed that entirely when I read your question.